# Can Identity Column help perform update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do updates over a table that contains over 600M lines on sql server, and this table does not contain the identity column, this is how it works by far :

```
UPDATE myTable set myBitColmun=1 where key='specifickey'
```

This kind of query takes over 1minute to update this specific line. And imagine the time needed to do updates on the whole table. And I need to do this kind of updates on my table everytime possible.

My question is : can identity column help perform update statement ?

```
alter table  myTable
add id int identity(1,1)
```

and change my previous query:

```
UPDATE myTable set myBitColmun=1 where id=specificId
```

Comment: What indexes and key columns are defined on the table?

Comment: An `IDENTITY` column is just one with a DB-generated unique value (aka "autonumber" or "autoincrement"). It is not necessarily a primary-key nor is it necessarily indexed.

Comment: Is there an index on key column? Update should not take long, it probably cannot find the record easily. Can you post table design?

Comment: Please provide the full create script for your table including indexes etc, you'll get a much better answer if you can include this in your original question.

Comment: You say "imagine the time needed to do updates on the whole table". Does that mean you are going to update ever row? No need for indexes in that case, they will only slow down the operation since thee need to be updated as well. Do the update in batches, to keep transaction size reasonable small. Perhaps 1000 or 10000 rows per update.

Comment: Do you update myBitColmun=1 for whole table at once..?